How to get human-mouse conservation score from UCSC
Maybe it is not suitable to post a such question here. But nobody response to me at Biostar.
I want to download conservation score data of human and mouse only from UCSC and then upload this data into IGV.
But I only get some information about conservation score at the Genome Browser or table Brower.
Though I found human related conservation score to other species here , hg38.phyloP4way.bw, this data contains four species and the size is huge.
This directory contains conversation scoring by phyloP (phylogenetic p-values) from the PHAST package (http://compgen.bscb.cornell.edu/phast/) for multiple alignments of 4 genomes to the Guinea pig genome.

Files in this directory are:
hg38.phyloP4way.mod  phyloP tree model with branch lengths
for the 5 genomes
hg38.phyloP4way.wigFix.gz - phyloP scores for the 5 genomes
in fixed step wiggle format
hg38.phyloP4way.bw - phyloP scores for the 5 species
in bigWig format
md5sum.txt - md5 sums of the files here to verify accurate download

I am afraid that it is not easy to load into IGV. And it is not necessary to focus on other three species here.
So could somebody tell me where and how to get only conservation score data of human and mouse ?
Or another way to extract specific species conservation score from hg38.phyloP4way.bw ?
Thanks in advance.
